# how to count unique elements of a cell in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to count unique elements of a cell array in Matlab. How can I do this? Thank you.

```
c = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'};
% count unique elements, return the following struct
unique_count.a = 2
unique_count.b = 1
unique_count.c = 1
```

Comment: Can it count numbers? What about combination of numbers and characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To count unique elements, you can combine [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/UNIQUE.html) with [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ACCUMARRAY.html)

```
c = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'};
[uniqueC,~,idx] = unique(c); %# uniqueC are unique entries in c
                             %# replace the tilde with 'dummy' if pre-R2008a

counts = accumarray(idx(:),1,[],@sum);
```

To produce the structure, use [NUM2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/NUM2CELL.html) and [STRUCT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html):

```
countCell = num2cell(counts);
tmp = [uniqueC;countCell']; %'

unique_count = struct(tmp{:}) %# this evaluates to struct('a',2,'b',1,'c') 

unique_count = 
    a: 2
    b: 1
    c: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [count_unique](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23333-determine-and-count-unique-values-of-an-array) on the file exchange.  It uses `accumarray` or `sort` depending upon which is the most appropriate.  It will also check for nans/infs.