# Using SUM and UNIQUE to count occurrences of value within subset of a matrix

Tags: matlab, sum, unique

So, presume a matrix like so:

```
20 2
20 2
30 2
30 1
40 1
40 1
```

I want to count the number of times 1 occurs for each unique value of column 1. I could do this the long way by [sum(x(1:2,2)==1)] for each value, but I think this would be the perfect use for the UNIQUE function. How could I fix it so that I could get an output like this:

```
20 0
30 1
40 2
```

Sorry if the solution seems obvious, my grasp of loops is very poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed unique is a good option:

```
u=unique(x(:,1))
res=arrayfun(@(y)length(x(x(:,1)==y & x(:,2)==1)),u)
```

Taking apart that last line:

1. arrayfun(fun,array) applies fun to each element in the array, and puts it in a new array, which it returns.
2. This function is the function `@(y)length(x(x(:,1)==y & x(:,2)==1))` which finds the length of the portion of x where the condition `x(:,1)==y & x(:,2)==1)` holds (called logical indexing). So for each of the unique elements, it finds the row in X where the first is the unique element, and the second is one.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Reading the 'help' entry doesn't help me understand how this argument works though; would you be so kind as to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285217/how-to-count-unique-elements-of-a-cell-in-matlab)):

```
>>> [c,~,d] = unique(a(a(:,2)==1))
c =
    30
    40

d =
    1
    3

>>> counts = accumarray(d(:),1,[],@sum)
counts =
    1
    2

>>> res = [c,counts]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have an array of various integers in 'array'

the [`tabulate`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/stats/tabulate.html) function will sort the unique values and count the occurances.

```
table = tabulate(array)
```

look for your unique counts in col 2 of table.