# How to count characters or unique string in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, count

So how to count no. of repeated letters occur in certain array>

for example i have a array

```
a
a
a
c
b
c
c
d
a
```

how can i know how may a,b,c,and  occur? i want an output like this:

```
Alphabet   count
a           4
c           3
b           1
d           1
```

so how can i do that? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = {'a' 'a' 'a' 'c' 'b' 'c' 'c' 'd' 'a'}

%// map letters with numbers and count them
count = hist(cellfun(@(x) x - 96,arr))

%// filter result and convert to cell
countCell = num2cell(count(find(count)).') %'

%// get sorted list of unique letters 
letters = unique(arr).' %'

%// output
outpur = [letters countCell]
```

The solution in the [**duplicate answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285217/how-to-count-unique-elements-of-a-cell-in-matlab) is very neat, applied to your desired output:

```
[letters,~,subs] = unique(arr)
countCell = num2cell(accumarray(subs(:),1,[],@sum))
output = [letters.' countCell]
```

---

It appears to me, that your input array rather looks like:

```
arr = ['a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'c'; 'b'; 'c'; 'c'; 'd'; 'a']
```

so change the last line to:

```
output = [cellstr(letters) countCell]
```

---

```
output = 

    'a'    [4]
    'b'    [1]
    'c'    [3]
    'd'    [1]
```

Comment: i tried it but it gives an error" Error using cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

Comment: @Raldenors please give an example how you create your input array